# Paho MQTT client: how to ignore messages published by myself?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

My Paho MQTT client does the following:

1. Subscribe to `mytopic/#`
2. Do *something*
3. Publish to `mytopic/#`

**Problem:**
The published message in step 3 arrives at step 1. I'd like to avoid adding a `sender`-attribute to the payload.

Is there a proper way of ignoring *self-published* messages? Something like the following (pseudocode):

```
def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
    if client.id == message.sender_client_id:  # Is there anything like the sender_client_id?
        return
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the MQTT v5 [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901169) you can tell the broker not to send your own messages back to you as part of the subscription message.

This removes the need to add the identifier so you can then choose to ignore it.

This does of course rely on both the broker and the MQTT client supporting MQTT v5

Answer (score 1):

This logic should work:

1. Assign an id to every client
2. every client publish on mytopic/{id}
3. every client sub to mytopic/#

ignore messages where message.topic starts with mytopic/{id}

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to touch the topics, but your solution should work. Thanks!

Comment: An id needs to sent, payload or topic its your design choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MQTT v5, you can pass the noLocal option to the paho client when subscribing. This option tells the broker not to send back your own messages.

```
from paho.mqtt.subscribeoptions import SubscribeOptions
...
options = SubscribeOptions(qos=1, noLocal=True)
client.subscribe('mytopic/#', options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
    if client.id == message.sender_client_id:  # Is there anything like the sender_client_id?
        return
```

In your pseudocode, you are asking for the client's identity but this is exactly opposite to the MQTT specification. In MQTT, two different clients are unaware of each other's identity, they only communicate via the MQTT broker by subscribing to the topics.